# Javascript slow in inactive tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run this function every time its work if the tab is active but in inactive tab javascript is very slow (i use chrome)

```
function request() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        encoding:"UTF-8",
        url: 'request.php',
        success: function(data) {
           request();
        }
   });
}
```

what is solution for this problem ? I have already tested with `setInterval()`

Thanks you

Comment: I recently had a problem like this, intervals don't work very fast when Chrome is not in focus. You can use a web worker instead. Also, this is a possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/5927432#12522580)

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Most likely Chrome is throttling that tab and making it run more slowly.

Comment: Thanks for reply u have an example with ajax request @penne12 ? For other browsers its work only with IE

Comment: Yeah look at the question I linked.

Comment: You speak about WebWorkers Code ? Because `stop(true,true)` not work and my function is not an animation just an ajax request